# Python, изменение данных другого процесса

Tags: python-3.x, windows, dll, процесс, code-injection

Всем привет, вопрос касается Python 3.x и ОС Windows.

Я знаю что Python в состоянии внедряться в другой процесс, как это например показано [тут](https://habr.com/ru/articles/151621/).
Информация довольно интересная, но, как мне показалось, пояснений к коду вроде "вот эта функция делает вот то-то" маловато, да и назначение кода из примера довольно таки примитивное - внедриться в процесс по его PID, убить из этого процесса другой процесс по его PID.

Мне же хочется получить информацию по боле менее продуктивному внедрению в другой процесс, скажем что-бы изменять в нем какие-нибудь данные.

Какой-то конкретики дать не могу, мне просто в голову пришла такая идея, но для примера можно взять скажем десктопный клиент Telegram.
Скажем мне нужно внедриться в процесс клиента Telegram, найти в нем список сообщений определенного чата, и изменить отображение содержимого сообщений.
Для того чтобы было понятнее чего я хочу, скину картиночку.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Собственно вопрос в том, в сторону чего мне копать, какую искать информацию ? Я перепробовал уже все что пришло на ум поискать в гугле, но чего-то вменяемого по теме не обнаружилось.

Comment: Что-то я сомневаюсь, что современные ОС такое позволят. Статья то старая. Да и антивирусы будут ругаться. Ну, их отключить можно, ладно. Но в чужой процесс залезть и там что-то поменять - это очень вряд ли. А, или там dll меняется как файл, до загрузки? Тогда может быть, хотя антивирусы точно будут недовольны.

Comment: @CrazyElf ну читы в современных системах вроде работают, а именно этим они и занимаются, внедряются в процесс, и что-то в нем меняют